# Prove $\frac1{(2a+b+c)^2}+\frac1{(a+2b+c)^2}+\frac1{(a+b+2c)^2}\le\frac3{16}$ when $a+b+c=\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove: if
>   $$a+b+c=\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c,\quad0<a,b,c,\in\mathbb R$$
>   then
>   $$\frac1{(2a+b+c)^2}+\frac1{(a+2b+c)^2}+\frac1{(a+b+2c)^2}\le\frac3{16}$$

All I tried was
$$2a+b+c=a+\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c$$
$$LHS=a^2b^2c^2\left(\frac1{((a^2+1)bc+ca+ab)^2}+\frac1{((b^2+1)ca+ab+bc)^2}+\frac1{((c^2+1)ab+bc+ca)^2}\right)$$
that didn't help at all. Thanks.

Comment: where did you find this bad boy :) ?

Comment: @A.Molendijk Somebody asked this question to me. I don't know the source either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is an exact copy of the one given on page 396 of the book *Olympiad Inequalities*, GIL Publishing House. The book also says that this problem was on the shortlist for the International Mathematical Olympiad 2009.

---

From condition we have $3(ab+ac+bc)=3abc(a+b+c)\leq (ab+ac+bc)^2\Longrightarrow ab+ac+bc\geq 3.$ From Am-Gm inequality it follows: $(2a+b+c)^2\geq 4(a+b)(a+c)$, so it's enough to prove: $$\sum\frac{1}{(a+b)(a+c)}\leq\frac{3}{4} \\ \Longleftrightarrow 8(a+b+c)\leq 3(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$$
Using condition, we can see that it's enough to prove: $$8(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)\leq 9(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$$ What is well known inequality and equivalent to: $c(a-b)^2+b(a-c)^2+c(a-b)^2\geq 0$. Equality holds when $a=b=c=1$.